# How to add UITapGestureRecognizer to an image within UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewlayout, uitapgesturerecognizer

Each of my cell's contain one imageView. The goal is to have it so that any time the cell (or imageView) is tapped or swiped the image changes with the corresponding tap or swipe animation. (The tap animation shrinks and then expands, while the swipe animation rotates the imageView 180 degrees)

At first I set up my tap functionality in my collection view's `didSelectItemAt` method and this worked fine. But, when I tried to add the swipe functionality I found that any user interaction with the cell would trigger the same tap animation.

SO, now I'm trying to set up the tap functionality in `cellForItemAt`. However, the tap selector for some reason is not being called. Any ideas why?

I am using a UICollectionViewController. Xcode 12, swift 5.

**EDIT**

Following @Sandeep Bhandari's suggestions I am now implementing a protocol to communicate between the cell (which holds a strong ref to the tap gesture) and UICollectionViewController. However, selector is still not being called.

**GameTileCell**

```
@objc protocol GameTileCellProtocol {
     func didTapImageView(for cell: GameTileCell)
}

class GameTileCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     // other properties
     var gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?
     weak var delegate: GameTileCellProtocol?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // call configure cell method
        
        gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        gameTileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        gameTileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture!)
        
    }
    
    // storyboard init
    // configure cell method defined
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.delegate?.didTapImageView(for: self)
        print("handleTap")
    }
}
```

**UICollectionViewController**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: GameTileCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! GameTileCell
        setImageAndColor(for: cell)
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
// other methods

extension GameTileCVC: GameTileCellProtocol {
func didTapImageView(for cell: GameTileCell) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        cell.gameTileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
    } completion: { (_ finished: Bool) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.setImageAndColor(for: cell)
            cell.gameTileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
    print(#function)
}
```

}

Comment: Added a new answer please check

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a tap gesture recognizer inside a `cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method which means its a local variable inside this method. Scope of this gesture recognizer is only inside this function `cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` as soon as control leaves the function's scope gesture recognizer will be deallocated and hence touch wouldn't work.

You need to hold the strong reference to the tap gesture recognizer, hence I would suggest moving this tap gesture recognizer from your ViewController to `GameTileCell` instead.

So change your `GameTiteCell` implementation to something like

```
class GameTileCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer
    weak var delegate: GameTitleCellProtocol?
    //other declarations of yours

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        gameTileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        self.gameTileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.delegate?.didTapImageView(for: self)
    }
}
```

Declare a protocol to communicate between your cell and your ViewController. Lets call it as

```
@objc protocol GameTitleCellProtocol {
    func didTapImageView(for cell: GameTileCell)
}
```

Finally, make your ViewController the delegate of your `GameTileCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: GameTileCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! GameTileCell
    setImageAndBgColor(for: cell)
    cell.delegate = self    
    return cell
}
```

Finally make your ViewController confirm to `GameTitleCellProtocol` protocol

```
extension YourViewController: GameTitleCellProtocol {
    func didTapImageView(for cell: GameTileCell) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            cell.gameTileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
        } completion: { (_ finished: Bool) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
                self.setImageAndBgColor(for: cell)
                cell.gameTileImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it another look over! I did implement your suggestions, but still am not seeing any change. I've placed print statements in `didTapImageView` and the `handleTap` selector but neither printed. The app doesn't crash, but nothing happens when the cell is tapped.

Comment: @melh0n: debug it one by one 1. Have you enabled user interaction on imageView? I have set it in init please check if init was triggered, were the statements inside it were executed 2. Is your tap selector being triggered? put a break point in `didTapImageView` and check if control reaches there ? 3. Have you set your view controller as cell's delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Finally when you say "nothing happens when the cell is tapped" tap gesture was added on imageView we are debugging only imageView tap and not cell tap, if cell tap isnt working its because of `allowsSelection` being

Comment: set to false which I wrongly mentioned in previous answer

Comment: I've edited the OP to include your suggestions as implemented. 1. Init is being triggered and user interaction is enabled. 2. Tap selector not being triggered! Control does not reach `didTapImageView` 3. VC is set as cell's delegate in `cellForItemAt indexPath` which I imagine is what you meant to say (not row).

Comment: Correct, tap gesture was added to imageView. My imageView is pinned to the edges of its cell so when the user taps the imageView they are also essentially tapping the cell... Oh, and `allowsSelection` is currently not set to anything.

Comment: Tap is working. Adding a print(gesture) to my cell's init shows me that every time I tap on an image, gesture is indeed printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add tap and swipe functionality to your cells, you need to define for each a separate gesturerecognizer:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(tapAction(_:)))
let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(swipeAction(_:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

As to why your selector action is not being called: Have you set a breakpoint on this line?

```
if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView)) {
```

I think the if might not turn out positive and thus leave your action without doing anything.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! The control doesn't even reach the breakpoint set at `if let indexPath`. I suppose this reaffirms my assumption that the handler isn't being called :\